# If "46 of the top 50" mobile apps are on Windows Phone 8, what are the other 4?

Tags: apps, store, 8.0

Yesterday, Microsoft announced that "46 of the top 50" mobile apps are on Windows Phone 8. What are these top 50 apps, and which 4 are missing from WP8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The four apps are:

- Instagram
- Viber
- Pinterest
- Wells Fargo

according to Joe Belfiore. [Source](http://www.theverge.com/2012/10/30/3573760/joe-belfiore-windows-phone-interview)

Comment: And of course, these are either now available, or coming...

Answer (score 3):

They didn't publish any list of apps. but I could find 3 of the 4 missing popular iphone apps

- Instagram
- Instapaper
- Flipboard

guess they looked at a combination of itunes charts and google's play store charts to make up the top 50

Comment: If anyone can find the 4th app, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the four apps referred might be the following.

- Instagram
- Voxer
- Wells Forgo
- Pinterest

For much more into the apps in market and whats not, I read this article which you might find interesting [Fact Check: Microsoft’s Claims About App Numbers for Windows Phone](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/10/fact-check-does-windows-phone-really-have-46-out-of-50-of-the-top-apps/). BTW, the author was a previous macworld author, so you might find it bit partial. But, anyways you just want to know the best apps so it will work :-P